# Selenium find button with Inspect element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem with find button. When I use "view source code" I can not find him, only I can see it when I use "Inspect Element". Is possible with selenium find > inspect element and click button?

> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='butsys minwd']").click()
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: share the relevant HTML ? code trials and error stack trace

Comment: Are you trying to wait for the element be visible or exists?

Comment: Also, it can be inside an iframe too... If it is, the source code from selenium will not show that